# Tapped event of RichTextblock

Tags: windows-store-apps, richtextblock, richtextblockoverflow

Why we can not handle the tapped event of richtextblock, I want to get the tapped point of the   richtextblock or richtextblockoverflow, how to workaround?

Comment: The events are there, what do you mean by "not handle the tapped event" ? Can you provide a self contained code sample illustrating the problem?

Comment: I just did a test, put a richtextblock in the main page, and add tapped event handler for the richtextblock, but the method will never be fired. And if I set the isselectionenable of the richtextblock to false, the tapped event can be handled. That the problem, thanks

Answer (score 3):

if you set IsTextSelectionEnabled to false its work but you cant use ScrollViewer to scroll i solved this with this issue

```
this.RichTextBlock.AddHandler(TappedEvent, new TappedEventHandler(RichTextBlock_Tapped), true);

private void medical_history_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

hope this helped you!

Comment: Thanks for this! Wasn't able to resolve this for quite sometime.